# Magento admin extension fails to show in live server menu bar

Tags: magento, admin

I have recently built my first Magento extenstion.

It involves adding a new menu item in the admin area and works perfectly on my development server.

On the live server however, the menu bar item fails to display.

I am pretty sure that all the files have been copied over and I have refreshed all of the cache.

I have checked the system > configuration > advanced area and the module is listed in the disable section.

**Are there any other settings/configurations I need to check?**

Comment: re save admin role of the group you are belonging, clear cache, log out and log in

Comment: have you find any solution? i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you setup your menu with ACL roles? If so, does your user have the correct role?

Assuming the above is true, the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` class is responsible for rendering the menus.  I'd start by adding some temporary debugging code to determine why this class is skipping your menu. (is it skipping it, or does it not know about it?  If it doesn't know about it, why isn't your system reading it from the config) etc. etc.